# How to identify a specific exception from CommunicationException class?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, exception, tls1.2

I have a WCF Service that is running on a server using the protocol TLS 1.2. My application, which uses .NET Framework 4.0, communicates with this service. It can communicate through TLS 1.2, with the code below:

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;`

The problem is that this code will only work if the customer machine have at least the .NET Framework 4.5 installed. Also, some clients have their own servers running this WCF Service, and those use TLS 1.0. I don't want these clients to forced upgrade the .NET Framework of their employees.

So, I want to handle the CommunicationException thrown by the WCF Service, when it cannot communicate through the default SecurityProtocol (TLS 1.0). This exception has the information below:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://quellon.espaider.com.br/FacilcorpHomolog/DocSite/DSAddIn.svc. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream exception.

When this specific exception is thrown, I'll use the code shown in the beginning and allow the communication between my application and the service.

I want to know if there is some property or method that I can use to identify when the CommunicationException is this one. The only thing that comes to my mind is using the Message property, which I think is not a good practice.

Comment: I never found another way then to hardcode the exception message into your source and compare it against that. You could try all the properties listed [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.communicationexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)